# Existe uma denominação para este trocadilho (junção de palavras que soam a outra)?

Tags: termos, figuras-de-linguagem

Depois de ter lido [uma tira da rúbrica Mal por Mal](https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/t31.0-8/11119890_472376202922581_6493327814211183519_o.jpg), fiquei a ponderar se existe uma denominação especificada na língua portuguesa para **a junção de palavras ou fragmentos de palavras tais que são pronunciadas como outras**: *express'arte* (expressar-te), *pint'arte* (pintar-te), *cant'arte* (cantar-te).

É certamente um trocadilho, mas esta definição é apenas de um jogo de palavras. Existe alguma forma de indicar precisamente este tipo de trocadilho?

Comment: A meu entender, a pergunta não tem nada a ver com o trocadilho

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma [figura de linguagem](http://www.significados.com.br/figuras-de-linguagem/) chamada *[cacofonia](http://www.significados.com.br/cacofonia/)* que ocorre quando uma palavra ou sílaba, em união com outras, formam expressões com sons desagradáveis ou ambíguas; com duplo significado.
Alguns exemplos:

- "Vi ela" = (viela)
- "Amo ela" = (moela)
- "A boca dela" = (cadela)
- "Uma mão lava outra" = (mamão)
- "Ela tinha" = (latinha)
- "Na vez passada..." = (vespa)

Caso a união de palvras tenha significado obsceno ou chulo, chama-se de *[cacófato](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=cac%F3fato)* e existem diversos [exemplos](http://wp.clicrbs.com.br/sualingua/2009/04/29/cacofatos/?topo=) de ambas figuras, tanto na literatura, quanto na música e jornalismo.

Comment: @E_net4, me parecem junções ambíguas na tira que mencionaste, como se o personagem quisesse dizer _expressar-te_, _pintar-te_, _enganar-te_, porém a união de sílabas de palavras distintas forma novas palavras como _expressar arte_, _pintar arte_ e _enganar arte_.

Comment: Nem por isso, porque houve um corte propositado da primeira palavra para fazer o trocadilho. Não é coerente dizer que há ambiguidade ou desagrado com a junção. Aliás, não é suposto haver desagrado.

Comment: @E_net4, não entendi seu argumento, quem sabe continuamos a discussão no chat?

Comment: Há uma engraçada que deriva de "sabes se o Paulo vem?"  alguém sabe qual é?